# How to advertise data in my WiFi Direct service

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi-direct

I am writing a UWP app that uses WiFi Direct. I want to advertise a service so other machines can find it. My code so far:

```
WiFiDirectServiceAdvertiser advertiser = new WiFiDirectServiceAdvertiser("myservice");
advertiser.Start();
```

But I also want to include additional information in the service so other devices can read it. In my Android implementation, my service has a string map containing information about my service:

```
IDictionary<string, string> record = new Dictionary<string, string>();
record.Add("port", "1234");
record.Add("somedata", "data");
```

And other Android devices can read it while discovering WiFi Direct services (before connecting to it). How do I do the same in my UWP implementation?

Comment: Start by typing in cmd.exe following command >Arp -a which will give a list of all IP addresses in you local network which includes all the WiFi addresses.  You can search web for c# code that will get the ARP table.  A ARP response is what is return from the PING message.  Whenever any IP device is turned on it will advertise itself using ARP,  Also every device normally will send out an ARP message every 30 minutes.  Not sure if Android Devices impliment ARP but I think so.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all...

Comment: I think you then want to send a UDP Broadcast message on a known port.  I was looking at the issue from the other direction of finding IP addresses in your subnet.  You could the try to connect to each IP in the subnet.  My method is a little more secure since you are not sending any data.

Comment: I'm using Wifi Direct, at the stage where devices discover each other. There are no IP addresses at this point.

Comment: Wifi is HTTP which uses TCP as the transport layer.  All uses IP.  Wifi may block direct access from one PC to another.  If my idea works you can simply Broadcast a message and then have other PC check for the broadcast message.  There is no difference between WIFI and an Ethernet cable except WiFI hardware layer is radio instead of a piece of wire.

Comment: It will later need to work with mobile devices too

Comment: How do you advertise in a mobile network????

Comment: Please check the [Wi-Fi Direct services sample-Scenario5](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/WiFiDirectServices/cs/Scenario5_SendData.xaml.cs) to see if it's what you want.

Comment: @jdweng Wi-Fi is not HTTP. The question is about Wi-Fi Direct service discovery (NSD), not even TCP nor IP. The peers are not connected yet.